# Manage cancellation on the Token in a .NET Core 3.0 Worker Service

Tags: background-service, .net-core-3.0

I'm developing my first .NET Core 3.0 Worker Service to run it as a Windows Service.

Here there is the code I used for the test.

Debugging I see that stopping the windows service, the StopAsync() will be executed, but the ExecuteAsync() terminates due to the exception OperationCanceledException (thrown from the line Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken)).
Of course I can catch it but what I would like to do is complete the method flow in order to exit gracefully.

**Is there any way to avoid the exception and just exit according to the while condition?**

```
namespace Enerj.MyAppCore.WorkerService
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        bool exit = false;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _logger.LogInformation("ctor");
        }

        public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Start");
            await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }

        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Stopping");
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY SOLUTION

As evident from the code, the application spends almost all the time in the Task.Delay, so it is correct that Exception is thrown from that code.

I changed the code as follows.

```
while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Worker running at: {DateTime.Now}");

    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Error running at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    // Other code
}
```